# How to find and click the Like button on Facebook page using Selenium python

Tags: python, facebook, selenium-webdriver

I have a problem finding the way to click the like button on Facebook, I have tried many ways, I paid a lot of money to receive help and so far no one could help me! Does anyone have any idea  how I can do it?

```py
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[contains(., 'Me gusta')]"))).click()
```

Comment: can you provide more details about your program, and how you are using this code

Comment: In a single page, there can be multiple "Like" buttons. You have to create an XPATH expression that targets only one. Starting your expression with `//*` is almost guaranteed to fail because your relative parameter is way too broad. That said, Facebook seems to be built in a way that makes relative XPATH (and other locator strategies) very difficult because of the lack of element attributes (like ID) that would make relative location easy. You may have to use array notation like `//div[x]` where "x" is the index of the targeted element.

Comment: Unfortunately, you will have to be willing to share your page, and provide more specific details about what you need to do in order for any help to be meaningful.

Comment: This is an example of an XPATH expression for one of the "Like" buttons on my Facebook: `//*[@id="mount_0_0_fV"]/div/div[1]/div/div[5]/div/div/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[3]/div/div[3]/div/div/div[3]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[8]/div/div/div[4]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]`. This was generated from Chrome Dev Tools. You can see how not reusable this XPATH is. Good luck to you.

Comment: just out of interest, what is the use case for this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can utilise that Facebook adds the `aria-label` accessibility attribute to like buttons? For instance, this XPath expression will target all like buttons in both posts and comments that has been loaded on the page:

```py
//div[contains(@aria-label, "Like")]
```

For instance, you can use the [Browserist](https://jakob-bagterp.github.io/browserist/) extension to Selenium to get and click the elements. Something like this:

```py
from browserist import Browser

browser = Browser()
browser.open.url("https://www.facebook.com/")

# Assuming that you log in to Facebook here.

like_buttons = browser.get.elements("//div[contains(@aria-label, 'Like')]")

for like_button in like_buttons:
    like_button.click()
```

In full disclosure, I'm the author of the [Browserist](https://jakob-bagterp.github.io/browserist/) package. [Browserist](https://jakob-bagterp.github.io/browserist/) is lightweight, less verbose extension of the Selenium web driver that makes browser automation even easier. Simply install the package with `pip install browserist`.

Notes:

- [Browserist](https://jakob-bagterp.github.io/browserist/) doesn't need explicit conditions like `WebDriverWait`, `expected_conditions` or `element_to_be_clickable` – it's already built in so you don't have to worry about it. Instead, [Browserist](https://jakob-bagterp.github.io/browserist/) awaits an element to be fully loaded before it interacts with it. More on this concept [here](https://jakob-bagterp.github.io/browserist/#difference-from-selenium).

I hope this is helpful. Let me know if you have questions?